# Select 3 columns to one without union

Tags: mysql

I try to select three columns (TEXT - The same type) to one column without using union (System required), but I can't think on right way to do so.

```
select count(distinct(r)) as count 
from (
    select column1 as r from Table1
    union all
    select column2 as r from Table1
    union all
    select column3 as r from Table1
) a
```

This is the original query,
I tried to use CONCAT and COALESCE, but it isn't what I want.
I don't want to merge two string into one,
I want that all the select line will be in the same column.

For example -  [example - img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kcV1.png)

3 columns - to, cc and bcc (email recipients).
I want to know how much people I send emails.
Without double the emails (everyone can be on any column)

Thank you for your help!
I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No UNION, but even uglier. I join the table with itself and take the first 3*TABLE_LENGTH rows, because I need to process three different columns.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT if(rank<=@size, recipient, if(rank<=2*@size,cc,bcc)))
FROM
  (SELECT (@rank:=@rank+1) AS rank,
          s1.recipient,
          s1.cc,
          s1.bcc
   FROM sent AS s1
   JOIN sent AS s2) AS multi,

  (SELECT @rank:=0) AS dummy1,

  (SELECT @size:=
     (SELECT count(1)
      FROM sent)) AS dummy2
WHERE rank <= 3*@size
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14ac8a/14/0

Answer (score 1):

Either use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email) FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT firstColumn AS email FROM table 
  UNION 
  SELECT DISTINCT secondColumn AS email FROM table
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT thirdColumn AS email FROM table) AS Recipients
```

Even better: since you're running `DISTINCT` on the outer query, don't waste time doing that in your inner queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email) FROM (
  SELEC firstColumn AS email FROM table 
  UNION 
  SELEC secondColumn AS email FROM table
  UNION
  SELEC thirdColumn AS email FROM table) AS Recipients
```

See example fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edda57/10

Comment: Terry, thank you. Very elegant answer but i need an solution without UNION.

Comment: Eventually, i choose to use this query despite the union

Answer (score 0):

Simply use alias into a concat :) example here :

```
SELECT CONCAT(to, cc, bcc, year) as new_colum_mailing FROM `mailing` .. WHERE    ...
```

Comment: headmax, thank you but it seems to 'merge' the strings. For example: TO: nofar, CC:nofar2, BCC:nofar3 TO: nofar2, CC:nofar4, BCC:nofar

So, in your example it gonna be * nofar nofar2 nofar3 * nofar2 nofar4 nofar

I want the output to be 4. (nofar, nofar2 nofar3 nofar4)

Comment: May be just add a DISTINCT after select duplicate can be filter.